# PHP SQL Update text field size issue

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a SQL db update issue where I can not update a particular field.

The db has a field  called media_gallery this is set as text. if I look at the db directly i can paste the offending string into the field without any issues.
Already tried setting the char count of field to 2000 with no difference

offending strings are 800 - 1600 char long and contain only semicolon separated URLS ( hence unable to paste here) only odd char's  in the string  are   `https://www.xxxxx.co.uk/xxx/xxx/xxx/xx_xx.xxx;https://www.xxxxx.co.uk/xxx/xxx/xx_x/xx_xx.xxx` etc   and `;` as the separator between urls.

shorter versions of string say 300 char are updated correctly.

Code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE build_table SET  media_gallery = '$Image_Gallery' WHERE Code = '$ode';");
$stmt->execute();
```

if I change the code to below all updates correctly.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE build_table SET  media_gallery = 'GRRR TEST https://www.xxxxx.co.uk/xxx/xxx/xxx/xx_xx.xxx;https://www.xxxxx.co.uk/xxx/xxx/xx_x/xx_xx.xxx' WHERE Code = '$ode';");
$stmt->execute();
```

So the question is why is the `media_gallery`  blank / not updated for the larger rows ?

Comment: Where do `$Image_Gallery` and `$ode` come from? You're using prepared statements, yet your code may still be open to SQL injection!

Comment: Does not appear to matter as even if i  $Image_Gallery = ' https://www.xxxxx.co.uk/xxx/xxx/xxx/xx_xx.xxx;https://www.xxxxx.co.uk/xxx/xxx/xx_x/xx_xx.xxx';   just above the Update code, it   works for small size and not the larger size, so same issue. even tried stripping the php down to just the update and the $ set as above with the same result.

Comment: Smells like an encoding issue. Are your strings utf16 or similar? Maybe when inserting to the database directly the encoding is different to when it is in your code, so the strings are actually twice as long as you think they are

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys,

Working solution.. not 100% sure why but swapped:

```
    $conn = mysqli_connect(
```

for

```
    $conn = new PDO(
```